# Mismatch of return datatype

Tags: java, multithreading, callable, countdownlatch

i am facing a problem regrading specifying the return data type. I have the `FOComp` class which implements callabale, the call() method of the 'FOComp' returns data type `List<ArrayList<Mat>>` as shown in the code of 'FOComp' class below.

and the method 'getResults()' returns data of type `ArrayList<Mat>` as shown in the code below. and currently, at run time, when I execute the code, I receive the folowing error:

Multiple markers at this line

- The return type is incompatible with  `Callable<ArrayList<Mat>>.call()`
- The return type is incompatible with  `Callable<List<Mat>>.call()`

kindly please let me know how to fix it.

**'FOComp' class**:

```
    static class FOComp implements Callable<List<Mat>> {//should return list contains 4 mats(0,45,90,135)

    private ArrayList<Mat> gaussianMatList = null;
    private List<ArrayList<Mat>> results_4OrientAngles_List = null;

    public FOComp(ArrayList<Mat> gaussianMatList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.gaussianMatList = gaussianMatList;
        this.results_4OrientAngles_List = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Mat>>();
    }
    public List<ArrayList<Mat>> call() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            featOrient = new FeatOrientation(this.gaussianMatList);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            featOrient.start();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.results_4OrientAngles_List.add(featOrient.getResults());

        return results_4OrientAngles_List;
    }
}
```

**'getResults'**:

```
public ArrayList<Mat> getResults() {
    if (this.crossAddOrientMapsList != null) {
        if (!this.crossAddOrientMapsList.isEmpty()) {

            if (this.crossAddOrientMapsList.size() == 4) {
                double[] theta = new double[4];

                theta[0] = 0;
                theta[1] = 45;
                theta[2] = 90;
                theta[3] = 135;

                for (int i = 0; i < this.crossAddOrientMapsList.size(); i++) {
                    MatFactory.writeMat(FilePathUtils.newOutputPath("FinalCrossAdd_" + theta[i]+"_degs"), this.crossAddOrientMapsList.get(i));
                    //ImageUtils.showMat(this.crossAddOrientMapsList.get(i), "OrientMap_" + theta[i] + " degs");
                }

                return this.crossAddOrientMapsList;

            } else {

                Log.WTF(TAG, "getResults", "crossAddOrientMapsList != 4 !!");
                return null;
            }

        } else {
            Log.E(TAG, "getResults", "crossAddOrientMapsList is empty.");
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        Log.E(TAG, "getResults", "crossAddOrientMapsList is null");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class FOComp implements Callable<List<Mat>>
```

and

```
public List<ArrayList<Mat>> call()
```

aren't really compatible... Your `call()` method should be

```
@Override public List<Mat> call()
```

Also, it is good practice to avoid implementation classes in method signatures, use the interfaces instead (in this case, use `List` rather than `ArrayList`). That will also fix your problem with one of the "multiple markers" :-)

Cheers,

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what i could not understand in you answer is, that point you mntioned regarding avoiding implementing classes in method signature! would you please point out where iam doing so?? sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Sure: `public List<ArrayList<Mat>> call() throws Exception {`

Comment: thanks again, but can u please tell me how to use interfaces to avoid this?

Comment: First of all, that return type is wrong compared to the `Callable<List<Mat>>` you implement. Secondly, replace occurrences of eg. `ArrayList` with `List` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You class declaration says that you are going to return a List of Mat (`FOComp implements Callable<List<Mat>>`), but your `call` method signature says you are going to return a List of ArrayList of Mat (`List<ArrayList<Mat>>`).

You will need to make them consistent.